# PowerShell command to check the XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to learn accessing XML files through PowerShell.

The requirement is to check through PowerShell and see if the `<street>Baker street 1</street>`  exist in all the three xml files.

Below are the 3 XML file and its path:

Path C:\Desktop\Path1\XML Path

**1. Joe.xml**

```
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
    <address>
        <street>Baker street 1</street>
        <name>Joe Tester</name>
        <age>20</age>
        <university>A - UNIVERSITY</university>
    </address>
</addresses>
```

**2. Jack.xml**

```
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
    <address>
        <name>Jack</name>
        <age>19</age>
        <university>B - UNIVERSITY</university>
    </address>
</addresses>
```

**3. Ryan.xml**

```
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
    <address>
        <name>Ryan</name>
        <age>23</age>
        <university>C - UNIVERSITY</university>
    </address>
</addresses>
```

If the `<street>Baker street 1</street>` does not exist:

1. PowerShell should provide the name of the xml file where the `<street>Baker street 1</street>` path is not added.
2. I need to update the `<street>Baker street 1</street>`  in the 2 xml file.

I managed to get the output for 1st scenario

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path C:Desktop\Path1\XML\*.* |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      HasCRLF = (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $_.FullName).Contains("<street>Baker street 1</street>")
      Name = $_.Name
      FullName = $_.FullName
    }
  }  
  
  
HasCRLF Name     FullName                     
------- ----     --------                     
  False Jack.xml C:\Desktop\Path1\XML\Jack.xml
   True Joe.xml  C:\Desktop\Path1\XML\Joe.xml 
  False Ryan.xml C:\Desktop\Path1\XML\Ryan.xml
```

Need your help to add the missing info to the xml file.

Comment: *is throwing error* is a useless problem description, unless you provide the **exact, complete error message** that you're getting. You need to provide specific details here if you're expecting us to be able to help.

Comment: Your immediate problems: `H:\Desktop\Path1\XML Path\*.xml` contains a _space_ char. and must therefore be _quoted_. `Select-Xml` has no `-r` (`-Recurse`) switch. The XPath query must be `'/addresses/address/street'` (full path from root, case-sensitive).

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the path where the xml files can be found and load each file as XmlDocument. Then the easiest would be to use the 'dot' notation to see if 'Baker street 1' can be found.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Desktop\Path1\XML' -Filter '*.xml' -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        # get all content as XML. Use this syntax, so you will get the encoding right
        $xml = [System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()
        $xml.Load($_.FullName)
        [PsCustOmobject] @{
            HasStreet = ($xml.addresses.address.street -eq 'Baker street 1')
            Name      = $_.Name
            FullName  = $_.FullName
        }
    }
```

Using 'dot' syntax works case-insensitive, so `$xml.Addresses.Address.Street` is also fine as well as `BaKeR StReEt 1`

Output:

```
HasStreet Name     FullName        
--------- ----     --------        
    False Jack.xml D:\Test\Jack.xml
     True Joe.xml  D:\Test\Joe.xml 
    False Ryan.xml D:\Test\Ryan.xml
```

---

If you need to add the missing `<street>` tag to the files that do not have it, you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Desktop\Path1\XML' -Filter '*.xml' -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        # get all content as XML. Use this syntax, so you will get the encoding right
        $xml = [System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()
        $xml.Load($_.FullName)
        if (!$xml.addresses.address.street) {
            Write-Host "Adding node '<street>Baker street 1</street>' to file $($_.FullName)" 
            $streetNode = $xml.CreateElement('street')
            $streetNode.InnerText = 'Baker street 1'
            [void]$xml.addresses.address.AppendChild($streetNode)  # or use PrependChild() if <street> must come on top
            $xml.Save($_.FullName)
        }
    }
```